# Obj-C: [__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to pass data from an `NSMutableArray` to an `NSDictionary`. It seems I do this successfully, however `XCode` throws me a crash when trying to display the passed data in `self.username.text`. Any idea why this is and how I can fix it? See code below.

**ViewController.m**

```
 -(void)calloutTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    OtherUserViewController *yourViewController = (OtherUserViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OtherUserViewController"];

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    dictionary = [self.addressData mutableCopy];

    yourViewController.mapuserData = dictionary; 

   [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];

}
```

**OtherUserViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

if (self.mapuserData != NULL) {
    NSLog(@"This is map user data %@", self.mapuserData);

    self.addFriend.hidden = NO;

    self.username.text = self.mapuserData[@"users_name"];
   NSLog(@"THIS IS IT %@", self.mapuserData[@"users_name"]);

    self.userBio.text = self.mapuserData[@"userbio"];

    NSString *thirdLink = self.mapuserData[@"photo_path"];

    NSString *ImageURLTwo = thirdLink;
    NSData *imageDataTwo = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURLTwo]];

    self.userPhoto.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageDataTwo];


}

if (neighbourDetail == NULL) {

    self.addFriend.hidden = YES;

    self.username.text = [self.myFriendData objectForKey:@"node_title"];
    NSLog(@"this is friend detail %@", self.myFriendData);

    self.userBio.text = [self.myFriendData objectForKey:@"body"];

    NSString *thirdLink = [self.myFriendData objectForKey:@"friendphoto"];

    NSString *ImageURLTwo = thirdLink;
    NSData *imageDataTwo = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURLTwo]];

    self.userPhoto.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageDataTwo];



} else {

     self.addFriend.hidden = NO;

    self.username.text = [neighbourDetail objectForKey:@"first name"];
    NSLog(@"this is neighbour detail %@", neighbourDetail);

    self.userBio.text = [neighbourDetail objectForKey:@"userbio"];

    NSString *secondLink = [neighbourDetail objectForKey:@"photo_path"];

    NSString *ImageURL = secondLink;
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];

    self.userPhoto.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];


}


NSString *testing = [self.myFriendData objectForKey:@"node_title"];
NSLog(@"This is the testing value %@", testing);

NSArray *friendorNo = self.checkfriendData;
NSLog(@"Friend or No Value %@", friendorNo);


for (NSDictionary *dict in friendorNo) {
    if ([dict[@"node_title"] isEqualToString:testing]) {
        self.addFriend.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

**Logged data passed succesfully to self.mapuserData:**

```
2017-06-14 22:03:49.397526-0700[3706:1178771] This is user data (
        {
        address = "2957 chill street";
        childrenunder = Yes;
        city = Vancouver;
        "emergency facility" = None;
        "first name" = josh;
        "last name" = tree;
        phone = 688;
        "photo_path" = "x.png";
        "points balance" = 24;
        "postal code" = b6b6v5;
        "profile photo" = "<null>";
        "property type" = Apartment;
        province = ont;
        "special skills" = "None";
        "star rating" = 0;
        "street_address" = none;
        supervision = Yes;
        uid = 182;
        userbio = nfkkdkckmfkekxkx;
        "users_name" = "josh_tree@hotmail.com";
    }
```

Comment: Try  -->       `self.username.text = [[self.mapuserData objectForKey:@"users_name"]objectAtIndex:0];`

Comment: @Zck No dice - error still occurs.

Comment: @PiyushPatel "Expected method to read array element not found on object of type NSDictionary" is the red flag XCode throws me when I use that.

Comment: @Brittany your Logged data shows its Array of Dictionary, is `self.mapuserData` Dictionary or Array?

Comment: Check what classes of your objects are.

Comment: What is the type of self.mapuserData ?If it's array then how you can assigned dictionary to it? You can add as object only

Comment: @DSDharma self.mapuserData is an NSDictionary.

Comment: Try  [[self.mapuserData objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"users_name"];

Comment: @ArpitJain "No visible @ interface for 'NSDictionary' declare the selector 'objectAtIndex' "

Comment: @Brittany what is the type of self.addressData?

Comment: Try this  `NSMutableArray * arr =   [self.addressData mutableCopy];       
   NSDictionary * dic = arr[0];
     self.username.text = [dic objectForKey:@"users_name"];`

Comment: if addressData is array then change your code to     dictionary = [self.addressData[0] mutableCopy];

Comment: I think `[self.addressData firstObject]' will be the `NSDictionary`

Comment: exactly..that's why she got error

Comment: set `NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    dictionary = [[self.addressData firstObject] mutableCopy];

    yourViewController.mapuserData = dictionary;` Then `self.username.text = [self.mapuserData valueForKey:@"users_name"];`

Comment: @DSDharma Changing to dictionary = [self.addressData[0] mutableCopy]; seems to have worked! No crash and data is passed, however nothing is appearing in my label? Note in my OtherViewController I'm using: self.username.text = self.mapuserData[@"users_name"];

Comment: Just print your dictionary & [dictionary valueForKey:@"users_name"];  then see what u will get.

Comment: 1. Please add the stacktrace to your Q. 2. Obviously you try to set an instance of an array to a string property.

Comment: @DSDharma SO strange lol. I log that line, and it gives me exactly what I'm looking for (josh_tree@hotmail.com)! Why on earth would it not be displaying in my label??

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad See my last comment.

Comment: put this `NSLog("%@", [self.mapuserData objectForKey:@"users_name"])` inside your `viewDidLoad` method and see if the output prints or not.

Comment: @nayem Yes, it does print out! See above comment.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly above your label.Just give static value to your label & check whether it displays or not.Check your view part also have u outletted correctly.

Comment: Ah see my edit above! It appears as though my full if statement was blocking the text from displaying? Any idea how I can fix this? See edits in OtherUserViewController for full nested if statements. @DSDharma

Comment: Instead of checking if (self.mapuserData != NULL) put [self.mapuserData count] > 0 .

Comment: Label still not visible. @DSDharma If I mute my other two if statements though it shows up fine.

Comment: you are setting `self.username.text` when `if (self.mapuserData != NULL)` &  `if (neighbourDetail == NULL)`. What's out of this: `NSLog(@"this is neighbour detail %@", neighbourDetail);`. Please update the Log

Comment: Fixed @DSDharma :) I simply added else if { to my second if statement!

Comment: @Brittany glad to help.Just debug everything it's the key to identify problems easily.

Comment: @Brittany the data you are passing to OtherUserViewController is of type NSArray as i can see the log message that you added. But you are assigning it to an NSDictionary and trying to access it. Please check the data that you received.

Comment: I do not see the stacktrace in your last comment. Moreover: 1. Did you check for the class, you applied `-objectForKey:` on? 2. Do you know the result of `-objectForKey:` applied on an array. The solution is not that difficult, if you debug your code instead of starting a guessing working group.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing an array.

Can you try this:

```
_username.text = [self.mapuserData firstObject][@"users_name"]
```

So, basically self.mapUserContent is an array of dictionary. What we did is get the first object and from the first object we get the username.

let me know if this works

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call `objectForKey:` for `NSArray` object.

> `self.addressData` is a kind of `NSArray`

**FIX:**

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
dictionary = [[self.addressData firstObject] mutableCopy];
yourViewController.mapuserData = dictionary;
```

Comment: This works (kind of) and no crash occurs however my label is now empty?

Comment: SO strange lol. I log the line that's supposed to display data in my username label, and it gives me exactly what I'm looking for (josh_tree@hotmail.com)! Why on earth would it not be displaying in my label??

Comment: you are setting `self.username.text` when `if (self.mapuserData != NULL)` & `if (neighbourDetail == NULL)`. What's out of this: `NSLog(@"this is neighbour detail %@", neighbourDetail);`. Please update the Log